# Erro na execução do comando cordova build

Tags: java, android, apache-cordova

Estou executando o comando `build cordova` (depois de terminar as configurações exemplificadas neste link: [PhoneGap O Comando-Line Interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)).

Mas os Node.js retorna este erro:

> Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
>   Preparing android project
>   Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c 
>   C:\Net\Phonegap\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build
>   Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant" debug -f "C:\Net\Phonegap\hello\platforms\android\build.xml"":
>   BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>   Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>   It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
>
> Total time: 2 seconds
>
> > at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\myuserpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\compile.js:65:22)
> >     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
> >     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
> >     at Socket. (child_process.js:956:11)
> >     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
> >     at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)

Meu config.xml

```xml
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
  <name>HelloWorld</name>
  <description>
     A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
  <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://phonegap.com">
     Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="WebViewBounce" value="true" />
  <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
  </feature>
</widget>
```

E meu AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Minha dúvida é, o que esta faltando para que o comando `cordova build` funcione corretamente?

Meu Path esta configurado certo. Adicionei a variável `JAVA_HOME` com o caminho correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>
> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>   It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

Se me recordo bem, de fato não existe um compilador Java na pasta JRE. Creio que seu problema é esse mesmo: ou você atribuiu `JAVA_HOME` para a pasta errada ou você não tem um compilador Java instalado no seu ambiente (i.e. você precisa do [Java SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)/JDK, e não do JRE).

Se você tem uma pasta tipo `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7"` ou algo assim, é para aí que seu `JAVA_HOME` deve apontar.

Comment: Verdade, esqueci de me atentar a isso (Ao principal) Tenho apenas o JRE e atribui o `JAVA_HOME` para o caminho `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar o build na plataforma android é necessário instalar a JDK, Apache Ant e a Android SDK. Também é preciso configurar as seguintes variáveis de ambiente no SO: JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME e ANT_HOME.